# Use wp_remote_get with javascript enabled ? (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, get

is there a way (or workaround) to fetch page with Wordpress using **wp_remote_get()** (or any other core function); and **javascript enabled** ?
I know there are tools like [phanthomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), but I'd like to stick with Wordpress functions.

Thanks !

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am looking for the same thing.

Comment: You could have a look at https://www.kimonolabs.com/, but it wasn't good for my needs...  Maybe you'll have more luck !

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that wp_remote_get() is a server-side/php function, while javascript is a client side function.

If you were to embed a link that looked something like this, that might be a good start. PHP functions work through the POST/GET methods (and a couple others). So phrase the command that way and that'll help.

```
<a href="/retreive.php?param1=true">Get it</a>
```